# Intercepting disk write in Linux

Tags: linux, filesystems

I want to intercept every disk write operation in a Linux server. In detail, I want to catch every disk write operation right at the time when it happens and be able to work out which process initiated the call, where it is trying to write and so on. To make it simple, for now, I am concentrating on ext3 only. I am aware of auditfs and other 'watchers' which only will let you know once the operation has happened. As said earlier, I want to intercept as it happens and be able to retrieve all information about the operation (process information, target location, content being written). If there is an interrupt/call back kind of mechanism (for example receiving a notification of any write operation by a process, process group or session - pid, pgid, sid), it will be even better.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to intercept the `write()` system call, or intercept when the data is actually being sent to disk? Because the latter may be delayed because of buffering. And Unix uses a shared buffer cache, so multiple processes may be "responsible". And if the process uses memory mapping, there's no `write()`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Barmar. I want to replicate the write (and probably delete) operation somewhere else as it happens. I hope intercepting during disk write may be the right thing. I don't understand the `multiple processes may be responsible`. I am interested in the high level process that performs the write. Please suggest me the best option. Thanks.

Comment: Two processes both use `mmap()` on the same file. They each do some updates to the same page of the file through this shared memory. Eventually the page is flushed to disk -- which process information should be returned?

Comment: Let's take an example. If I save a file from a gedit what will the other process be writing to the same file? In this case I am only interested only in the gedit which I hope is the high level process (or will the second process bbe having the same pgid and/or sid as the gedit? In that case I am interested in the processes with same pgid/sid).

Comment: I'm just trying to point out that things can be more complicated than your simple example. Most of the time only one process writes to a file, but sometimes multiple processes write. Anyway, to do what you want, you'll probably need to write a kernel driver or extension of some kind.

Comment: Thanks Barmar. Will you please be able to point me out to a starting point for the solution i.e to start writing the kernel driver/extension?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea how to do such a thing.

Comment: Enterprise operating systems have something called an Audit log. Each system call has an audit_func() that is a no-op if auditing is not enabled; logs the syscall details in a file if enabled. Search for this feature and you will get an idea on how to intercept writes inside the kernel. NOTE: you can intercept in user space library as well...you may want to check libc implementation if a generic intercept feature is already suported.

Answer (score 1):

I did some searching on this very issue, and these look promising:
•   Copyhook Handlers - for MSDOS Shell, lodge an interception DLL in WinReg
•   NtSetInformationFile
•   Minifilters - I think these are portable for cross-platform
•   Installable File system drivers - well, of course

File Share type: some filesystems support audit and protection hardening, but may be only "After-The-Fact".

CopyHook looks promisingly simple: Intercepting shell file manipulation calls in windows:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776048.aspx

The driver-level stuff gets very hairy, very quickly ...